# find the average value of each event type on the day immediately after the event

Tags: sql, postgresql

If you have two tables:

```
"Events"
id int 
event_type varchar
event_date Date ("dd/MM/YYYY")

|         id          |     event_type   |    event_date   |
|---------------------|------------------|-----------------|
|          1          |         a        |    01/01/2001   |
|          2          |         b        |    01/02/2001   |
|          3          |         c        |    01/03/2001   |
|          4          |         c        |    01/04/2001   |
|          5          |         a        |    01/05/2001   |
|          6          |         b        |    01/06/2001   |
|          7          |         a        |    01/07/2001   |
|          8          |         b        |    01/08/2001   |
|----------------------------------------------------------|

"Values"
object_id int
date Date ("dd/MM/YYYY")
value float


|         id          |      value         |     date        |
|---------------------|--------------------|-----------------|
|          1          |         1.0        |    31/12/2001   |
|          2          |         2.0        |    01/01/2001   |
|          3          |         3.0        |    02/01/2001   |
|          4          |         4.0        |    31/01/2001   |
|          5          |         5.0        |    01/02/2001   |
|          6          |         6.0        |    02/02/2001   |
|          7          |         7.0        |    28/02/2001   |
|          8          |         8.0        |    01/03/2001   |
|          9          |         9.0        |    02/03/2001   |
|         10          |         1.1        |    31/03/2001   |
|         11          |         2.1        |    01/04/2001   |
|         12          |         3.1        |    02/04/2001   |
|         13          |         4.1        |    30/04/2001   |
|         14          |         5.1        |    02/05/2001   |
|         15          |         6.1        |    02/06/2001   |
|         16          |         7.1        |    02/07/2001   |
|         17          |         8.1        |    02/08/2001   |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

How would you find the average value of each event type on the day immediately after the event?

I've tried variations of the following but it doesn't seem to be working,

```
SELECT events.* FROM
  events INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                       event_type,
                            MIN(event_date) AS first_event_date
                     FROM   event
                     GROUP BY
                            id,event_type) AS fe
  ON events.id = fe.id
     AND events.date = fe.first_event_date;
```

Also, would it help to first select rows in a small date range around each event before finding the post-event averages?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.  How are the two tables related?  Where is an `event_id` or `value_id`?  What date do you care about?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what date that I care about? Also, this is the first time I'm asking a sql question, can you explain how I should present sample data? I want to find the first value_date after a given event_date for a given id and find the average value across all these value_date's. There is no event_id or value_id. The $id$ in both tables refers to the same object.

Comment: . . There are two dates, one in each table.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added sample rows for the two tables and made your suggested edits.